# ContentProvider onCreate is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an app which has a ContentProvider. The app listens for certain broadcast event. I have a service which uses the content provider. This service is started based on the broadcast event. Service runs in a separate process.Main application is also registered to receive the same broadcast.

If the App was not running when the Broadcast arrives.  I see that ContentProvider onCreate() is called twice. Since only one instance of ContentProvider is supposed to exist, I am not sure why this gets called twice.

My assumption is that before the main application is able to initialise the content provider completely, service is trying to use it which causes it to be initialised again.

I did not find anything in the documentation that says onCreate will be called multiple times. Is this expected?

Comment: call `Thread.dumpStack()` inside, also what do you return from `onCreate`?

Comment: I will try stack dump.  I return true always. If I attach the provider to service process using android:process in manifest. This issue is not seen.

Comment: also `Log.d` the value of `Process.myPid()`

Comment: dumpStack gives the same stack. But pid is different for each instance of onCreate(). Why would this happen? The first process should stick around longer.

Comment: what pids are those? try running `ps` command and find process names for them

Comment: Both are the main application process. but the first process before if goes of the top list shows state as Z. Assume it completed execution. second ones is sticking around longer. Why would first one go away so fast? Is it expected?

Comment: main application process? what are the names on the right side of `ps` command? and that is the package name of the component where `ContentProvider` is defined?

Comment: process name is my package name. Ya, that is where the contentProvider is defined according to the manifest.

Comment: what are the names on the right side of ps command? for those two different pids, just post those two lines of `ps` command

Comment: 1866 u0_a276  20   0   0% S    5 122960K  8976K  bg com.dev.android.app
1699 u0_a276  20   0   0% S    5 122791K  8028K  bg com.dev.android.app

Comment: so this is the same app: `com.dev.android.app` it is killed by the system and created again with different pid and it is normal that second `onCreate` is called , isnt it?

Comment: two processes which hosted the the ContentProvider. I ran top with zero delay so that I don't miss the process that dies. 1699 exited before 1866 was created. It was in Z state when it appeared last on the list. So it completed execution and exited normally.

Comment: google for `ps PROCESS STATE CODES`

Comment: Z is zombie. Zombie could be for normal exit also. Are you implying that it got killed for some reason. I assumed that the process will be reused to avoid the overhead of creating a new one.

Comment: do you have anything in the logcat regarding `com.dev.android.app` death? yes i think it was killed for some reason and recreated again - and yes, in normal cases it should not be killed as far as i know...

Comment: You are right. It is getting killed by ActivityManager. but I see that android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED notification is coming after the first instance ran. That could be the reason why this happened. I am not sure why it is like this. Although I know it is not supposed to be so.

Comment: PACKAGE_REMOVED? i dont get it... what PACKAGE_REMOVED?

Comment: I am trying an upgrade scenario. My app will listen for PACKAGE_REPLACED event. so the it would have triggered a new process to host the reciever. But removed should have come before that

Comment: wait, you are reinstalling a new apk and wondering why the process was killed? for me it it rather obvious...

Comment: My app will listen for PACKAGE_REPLACED event. so the it would have triggered a new process to host the reciever. But removed should have come before that

Comment: content provider exist only in the upgraded app to be precise.

Comment: but still, if you upgrade that app it has to be killed and started again thus `onCreate` called again

Comment: but in the older app the content provider is not existing. It is the upgraded app with contentprovider that got killed by a PACKAGE_REMOVED event.